# JAVA - Speedup hash map creation

Tags: java, hashmap

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have N lists of objects. Each object stores an ID field and a value field.

```
LIST A | ID1   v1  | ID2   v2  | ID3   v3  |
LIST B | ID1   v1' | ID2   v2' | ID3   v3' |
LIST C | ID1   v1''| ID2   v2''| ID3   v3''|
```

I need to create a hash map

```
Map<Integer,List<Double>>
```

like this:

```
------------------------
| ID1 |  v1  v1'  v1'' |
| ID2 |  v2  v2'  v2'' |
| ID3 |  v3  v3'  v3'' |
------------------------
```

For each list, I'm currenty using this code:

```
object_list.forEach( v -> {
        String id = v.getID();
        Double value = v.getValue();

        if(map.containsKey(id)){
            map.get(id).add(value);
        }
        else{
            List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(value);
            map.put(id, list);
        }
});
```

My question: could I perform this operation in a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `map.containsKey(id)` but just `map.get(id)` and check whether you get null or not.

Comment: You could use: `map.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)`

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? Are you really concerned by performance, or do you mean "More expressive" or "Terser"?

Comment: I don't think parallelism will improve it but: `object_list.parallelStream().collect(groupingBy(X::getID, mapping(X::getValue, toList())))`

Answer (score 8):

You can do it very expressively using Java 8's handy `computeIfAbsent` method:

```
objectList.forEach( v -> {
    List<Double> doubleList = map.computeIfAbsent(v.getID(), k->new ArrayList<>());
    doubleList.add(v.getValue());
});
```

Note that this will not necessarily run faster than your original solution. Its advantage is that it is clearer to read.

Comment: It actually might run faster because it internally does only one lookup whereas the OP's code does 2 (`containsKey()` and `get()`).

Comment: @Thomas it might, but it depends on all sorts of trade-offs, so it's best not to make any rash claims. I would guess it depends on the number of entries.

Comment: @slim I didn't make any claims though ("might" run faster is the key word here). ;)

Comment: When you remove the obsolete local variable, you can replace the block syntax by the expression syntax: `objectList.forEach( v -> map.computeIfAbsent(v.getID(), k->new ArrayList<>()) .add(v.getValue()) );`

Comment: @Holger Well, you could, but it doesn't help with performance, and it makes it slightly harder to read, so why do it? Extract-variable is a useful refactoring for readability. JIT will optimise away the intermediate variable.

Comment: @slim: I’m not objecting against local variables in general, but lambda expressions should be short and I do not agree that needing the curly braces and semicolon improve the readability in any way. You still can keep the white-space, even the line breaks, if you don’t like it too concise. It’s just not possible to keep formatting in a comment, so don’t judge by the appearance within in my comment.

Answer (score 6):

Using guava's multimap would be more straightforward.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Double> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Then you can just `put()`, guava handles the rest for you:

```
String id = v.getID();
Double value = v.getValue();
multimap.put(id, value);
```

If the id exists the value is added to it, else a new key is created.

Comment: Guava's multimap is a good alternative, but it needs modifying all the related parts of my project.

Comment: Well, you can always convert the multimap to your original Map with one line: `Map<Integer, Collection<Double>> foo = multimap.asMap();`

Answer (score 3):

The question is: why are you unhappy with your current performance?

Have you benchmarked your current code?

Is this code running more than; say 10K times per minute?

Do your users complain about a performance problem; and you did careful profiling and found *this* piece of code to be the culprit?

If you answered all of these questions with *no*, chances are that you do not have a problem.

And given the fact that you really have a problem here; of course, the solution from Kiltos might give some relief. But I think you should go even further and look into the overall data flow. Like: you assume you are  spending a lot of time *retrieving* this data from that existing list. Maybe you should investigate instead if you could avoid building that initial list; and instead provide the required data in a way that requires *less* transformation work in the first place!

Besides: you are already working with streams. Maybe you could go **parallel** here!

Comment: This is an entirely appropriate question, but it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, my users complain about a performance problem. I benchmarked my application and this point seems to be the bottleneck. In this step, data are retrieved from memory after a decompression operation. My tests revelaed that data retrieval and data decompression require the same amount of time. So, i started inspecting data retrieval step in order to evaluate if some optimization can be applied.

Comment: @fab I very much doubt that the code you've shared is the bottleneck. Have you used a real profiler? VisualVM is free.

Comment: @fab I ran it for a list of a million entries, with 100 keys, and it took 78ms. It took a lot longer for 10 million entries, but that's not going to be a code issue. That's going to be a memory tuning issue.

Comment: No, I relied only on the execution time of each step forming the workflow

Comment: @fab Profile it properly. Otherwise you're just wasting your time trying to optimise parts you don't know are slow.

Comment: @Fab Minor update ... I think the answer from Kiltos is giving you a good hint; but I got some more generic thoughts there.

Comment: @Fab if this step is taking a long time, check the times taken in the calls to `v.getID()` and `v.getValue()`. It's very unlikely to be the way you're adding them to the map that's taking the time. If these two method calls are not taking up too much time, then the next step would be to tune your hashmap. Check the HashMap constructor parameters.

Comment: @Fab also, if you can estimate the size of your lists for each ID, then use the ArrayList constructor to preallocate memory for the list, which will speed it up by avoiding reallocations and array copying.

Answer (score 1):

If by N items you mean their number is fixed then you can create a map of that size which does not expand when getting full.

```
Map<Integer,List<Double>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<Double>>(N, 1);
```